# Regarding buttons use at asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework-4

I made an asp.net website to select records from SQL database and it include the following buttons next - previous - last - first button

I'm done with the last and first buttons, though I'm facing a problem to create the rest...

I need to create next and previous button at asp.net application using ado entities framework; how can i do that?
I have tried several times but I keep failing...

the previous code is for next button –

```
int count=0; 
ERPDerasatEntities1 erp = new ERPDerasatEntities1(); 

if (count < (erp.store.Count() - 1)) 
   { count++; 
     var query = erp.store.OrderBy(t => t.IDs).Skip(count).FirstOrDefault();
     txtstoreid.Text = query.IDs.ToString(); 
     txtstorename.Text = query.Storename; 
   }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: int count=0;
        ERPDerasatEntities1 erp = new ERPDerasatEntities1();
        if (count < (erp.store.Count() - 1))
        {
            count++;
            var query = erp.store.OrderBy(t => t.IDs).Skip(count).FirstOrDefault();
            
                txtstoreid.Text = query.IDs.ToString();
                txtstorename.Text = query.Storename;   
        }
the previous code is for next button

Comment: Which is primary key in this repository IDs ?

Comment: IDs is the primary key